# Find the $LU$ decomposition of a Laplacian like matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, recursion, lu-decomposition

#### Question:

We have a matrix defines as follow: $\underline{\underline{A_n}} = \begin{pmatrix}
1  & -1   & 0   & ... &0 \\ 
-1 &  2   & -1  &  ...&0\\ 
 0 & -1   &  2  & ... &-1\\ 
 0 & 0    & &...  -1&   2 &
\end{pmatrix}$ That means that all the elements (when $i=j$)on the diagonal are equal to $2$ and one element up to it and on his left is equal to $-1$. Except the element in the first row and the first column that is equal to $1$.
Prove that $ \forall n \geq 2 , det(\underline{\underline{A_n}})=1$ after find the $LU$ decomposition of $\underline{\underline{A_n}}$

#### My answer:

1-
By recursion.
*For $n=2$:* so $det\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-1 \\ 
-1 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}=1$
*For $n$:* We have $det(\underline{\underline{A_n}})=1$
*For $n+1$:* The matrix $\underline{\underline{A_{n+1}}}$ looks like this $\begin{pmatrix}
A_n & &  0 \\ 
 &&   -1\\ 
0 ...& -1  & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$ thus **WLOG with $n$ even** we have $det(A_{n+1})=2det(A_n)-(-1)det(A')=2det(A_n)+det(A')$ with $A'$ a matrix that looks like that: $\begin{pmatrix}
A_{n-1} &   0 \\ 
 &&   \\ 
0 ... -1  & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$.
So $det(A')=(-1)det(A_{n-1})+det(A'')$, with $A''$ a matrix that looks like this $A''= \begin{pmatrix}
1  & -1   & 0   & ... &0 \\ 
-1 &  2   & -1  &  ...&0\\ 
 0 & -1   &  2  & ... &0\\ 
 0 & 0    & &...  -1&   -1 &
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{n-2} &   0 \\ 
 &&   \\ 
0 ... -1  & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$
Thus $det(A'')=det(A_{n-2})-1det(A''')$ and $A'''$ itself can be expressed in the same way as before butwith $A_{n-3}$ at the place of $A_{n-2}$.
By continuing like this we get that $det(A_{n+1})=2det(A_n)-det(A_n)+det(A_{n-1})-det(A_{n-2})+...-det(A_2)=2-1=1$
Rem: if $n$ is even then $n-1$ and $n+1$ are odds.

I would like to know if my demonstration for the first part of the question is correct and mostly to get help in order to answer to the segond part.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps the "first part" of your problem is showing $\det A_n = 1$ and the "second part" is finding the LU decomposition of $A_n$.  If so, the approach of the first part by expansion by minors seems practical although some details are unclear.  For example the induction step includes an assumption "WLOG with $n$ even" that seems unjustified.

Comment: @hardmath yes you re right.  But as in the end we get a telescopic serie with the number of his elements depends of $n$ so it seems important to specify when $n$ is odd or not (if not the telescopit part doesn't not sum up to $1$ if I am not wrong).

Comment: The wording is strange, and so is the approach: once you have the LU decomposition, the determinant is trivial. That is, I would try to **first** compute the LU decomposition. Now, LU decomposition is little more than Gaussian pivoting, and here we have a tridiagonal system. What happens when you apply pivoting on the first column? I.e. when you add the first row to the second? What does the remaining submatrix look like? Can you prove it by induction and write the $L$ and $U$ factors?